# How to find missing .mp4 files in a directory?

Tags: php, comparison, filenames, glob, file-conversion

I have files likes this on my server:

```
aaaa.flv
aaaa.mp4
bbbb.flv
bbbb.mp4
cccc.flv
dddd.flv
dddd.mp4
```

This code isn't working:

```
$dir=$_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}."/test/";
foreach(glob($dir . "*.flv") as $file)
{
    $strip_ext=substr($file, 0, strrpos($file, "."));
    $mp4_ext=$strip_ext.".mp4";
    if (!file_exists($dir . $mp4_ext)) {
        echo "Non-matching pair! ".$strip_ext."<BR>";
    } 
}
```

How can I find my `.flv` files that don't have a matching `.mp4`?

I'd prefer to put a script in the directory and run it and have it spit out all the filenames without matching .mp4's, this would tell me files that I'll need to convert.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: These aren't uploaded files. They're already uploaded to the server.

Comment: use `glob` and `array_reduce`

Comment: _"I'd try glob but there is thousands of unqiue file names"_ - So? You still need to get the files somehow.

Comment: You could write a simple shell script or a php script. If you find them, then what?

Comment: Then I'll convert those flv files that don't have a matching mp4 to mp4 with ffmpeg. I just need to identify which I need to convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than doing iterated directory checks for if a given `.mp4` file exists, I'd rather try (and see if it chokes):

1. extracting all of the `.flv` files
2. extracting all of the `.mp4` files
3. isolate the missing `.mp4` files
4. start converting

Code: ([Mock Demo](https://3v4l.org/nFTkq))

```
chdir($_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}."/test/");  // change working directory so that glob's output excludes the path
$flvs=array_map(function($f){return basename($f,'.flv');},glob("*.flv"));  // store .flv's and strip suffixes
$mp4s=array_map(function($f){return basename($f,'.mp4');},glob("*.mp4"));  // store .mp4's and strip suffixes
$need_conversion=array_diff($flvs,$mp4s);  // run ffmpeg() on these suffix-free files
// $need_conversion = array( 4 => 'cccc' )
```

Comment: If this "doesn't work" please describe how it fails.  Have you successfully changed the directory with `chdir()`? Do you require case-insensitive file suffix matching? Does it simply crash do to directory volume?  Does it somehow generate an incorrect list?  Quality feedback is essential.